# jquery ajax call -submitting some form data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webpage containing numerous controls.Some of them are 'file' controls which i use to upload images.
I use JQuery Ajax call to upload images.I have got the code to upload images from the internet itself long time back.The code is give below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),<<------Submitting all the form data
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
    $("#gallery").html(data);
    },
    error: function(){}             
});
```

As you can see in the above code snippet, the entire form data are POSTED.Now suppose i don't post the entire data of the form but choose only to post data from the 
say first file control 'file_1'.How should i go about it??What should i write above marked with an arrow.Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `FormData` object and use its `append()` method to only add the data you require:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('foo', $('#bar').val());

$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: fd,
    // ...
});
```

Further reading on `FormData` available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Thanks @Rory for your answer, but can you tell what to write in the above if i want to submit the data contained in say one file control named file_1

Comment: It's in the documentation I linked to: `formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');`